# Asymptotics of $\sum_{m=1}^{n} n \mod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Let $\displaystyle a_n = \sum_{m=1}^{n} (n \mod m)$ where $0 \le n \mod m \le m-1$.

It appears that $a_n \sim Cn^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha = 2$ and $C \approx .177448$. Is this true, and if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [OEIS A004125](https://oeis.org/A004125). Your asymptotics are true and $C=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

This arises because
$$\sum_{m=1}^n(n\bmod m)=n^2-\sum_{m=1}^n m\lfloor n/m\rfloor$$
and Walfisz showed the asymptotics of the latter to be $\frac{\pi^2}{12}n^2$ (see [OEIS A024916](https://oeis.org/A024916) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1671986/357390)).

Comment: Thank you. I also just saw T^2’s answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195325/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-remainders-of-n/342889